# Change in the size of div element on resize of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two columns with select and button tag.

I have givn `100%` height to both of them.
When I try to resize the screen height of each element is getting changed .

How can I prevent this on resize of screen?

```css
#btn-folder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
background-color:rgb(194, 191, 191);
color: white;
padding: 12px 45px;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:16px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
#btn-folder:hover{
background-color:rgb(94, 89, 89);
}
.custom-selection{
  position:relative;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
.custom-selection select {
  display: block;
  border:none;
  background-color:white;
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  margin: 0;      
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row dropdown">
      <div class="col-sm-9 ">
        
        <div class="custom-selection">
            <select class="round" id="myselect">

              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 folder-btn">
            <button id="btn-folder" class="btn btn-light"> Open Folder</button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add ` text-nowrap px-2 ` class at  btn-folder id

Comment: You have to reduce left and right padding of button - `#btn-folder{padding: 12px 10px;}`

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY Tried this but when I resize page to around 650px text in button is overflowed

Comment: @PrakashRajotiya still getting changed when i resize more

Comment: Is there any other approach ?

Comment: you resize the screen height or width?

Comment: This is in your case a normal behavior cause you're using `%` unit. I your concept don't need that, just pass the 2 elements `px` as unit instead of `%` and you will be fine. But as I said, it depends on your concept and what you are trying the reach.